# Can handcuffs be picked with a single hand while handcuffed?

Tags: criminology

Many movies and series show people wearing handcuffs picking them using a small hidden piece of metal, like a bobby pin, paperclip, broken glasses, tweezers and more.

Can this be done in real life, with handcuffs that are used by police and other law enforcement agencies?

Comment: Going solely by the [profusion of instructional videos](http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=police+handcuffs+picking) on YouTube, I'd say yes.

Comment: I've seen it demonstrated in person by a police officer in "slow motion" (ie, no mirrors, "real" cuffs, etc) - yep. But I have no documented sources

Comment: Should this specify what type of handcuff? How about the rigid in the middle type? or the plastic type?

Comment: @superphonic - I'm having a bit of trouble finding an instructional video showing how to pick military handcuffs. But the OP did say, "used by police and other law enforcement agencies."

Comment: @Mazura Rigid handcuffs are used by the police here in the UK

Comment: From what I remember, on TV, the type that is usualy used is chain linked handcafs. If you have an answer that encompasses all types of handcafs, post it, or add the info to the existing answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes they can. This will show you how.
http://www.wikihow.com/Escape-from-Handcuffs

Also, fun fact for you.  Most handcuffs use a generic key that you could buy so you would not need to pick them, just unlock them.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Handcuffs#Keys